# C# кнопки событие по движению мыши

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача нажать клавишей мыши на кнопку и не отпуская протянуть по 10м другим кнопкам которые рядом находятся. Делаю обработку по собитию MouseDown регистрирую что нажата кнопка, а на других отлавливаю на Move или Hover но этих событий не возникает.
Видимо нажата клавиша блокирует события по движению.
Есть ли возможность выполнить задание?

Comment: интересный вопрос, попробую чуть позже. WinForms или WPF добавьте соответствующую метку к вопросу

Comment: Когда вы нажимаете на кнопку, происходит mouse capture, и все события от мыши после этого доставляются **только этой кнопке**. Подпишитесь у неё на MouseMove и анализируйте координаты.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать DrugAndDrop. Вот тебе пример:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bool mouseDown = false;

            button1.MouseDown += (s, e) => mouseDown = true;
            button1.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (mouseDown)
                    button1.DoDragDrop(button1, DragDropEffects.Move);
            };
            button1.MouseUp += (s, e) => mouseDown = false;


            button2.AllowDrop = true;
            button2.DragEnter += (sender, e) => Text = ((Button)sender).Text;
        }
}
```

Comment: Подход интересный. Однако, для этого нужно у всех кнопок (у топикстартера их 10) регистрировать кучу событий. Многовато кода получается. Подход, предложенный VladD с анализом координат в `MouseMove`, имхо, будет намного проще.